# Type error: invalid 'in' operand e in jquery 1.10.2?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a js file Im using to make a simple fading slideshow. It works fine when used by itself, but Im trying to convert it into a function so I can instantiate it. A function that was working before is now giving me this error:

Type error: invalid 'in' operand e in jquery 1.10.2v

Im guessing this is something about jquery I have no concept of. When running through the steps in firebug the error popups at the "$(top).delay" line. Here's my code.

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.pictureFade = function( options ){

    var images = options.images;    


    i = 0;
    var top = $("#topImage img");
    var bottom = $("#botImage img");

    //Set first images
    $(top).attr("src", images[i]);
    $(bottom).attr("src", images[i+1]);  

//  $(top).fadeToggle(4000, function(){     });

    toggleDiv("top");

    };
    function toggleDiv(pos){

        if(pos == "top"){
                $(top).delay(2000).fadeToggle(4000, "linear", function(){
                    i++;
                    if(i == images.length-1)i = -1;
                    $(top).attr("src", images[i+1]);
                    toggleDiv("bottom");    
                }
            );  
        }   

        if(pos == "bottom"){
                 $(top).delay(2000).fadeToggle(4000, "linear", function(){
                    $(bottom).attr("src", images[i+1]);  
                     toggleDiv("top");

           }

           );

        }   
}
})( jQuery );
```

Update: I just noticed that if I put the toggleDiv function inside the "$.fn.pictureFade" function then it works fine. I always thought separate functions should be outside of it. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

```
var top = $("#topImage img");
```

`top` is already a jQuery object, you should not wrap it again by `$(top)`,

just do like `top.delay(...`,`top.attr("src", images[i+1]);` and so on.

Comment: Removing the $ from $().delay gave me an error, but top.attr worked.